# Best MySQL query for performance

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have this mysql database, where I need to perform a larger MySQL query.
User A has a row in a table called users. In the value of a field called "trackers" there is a comma seperated value with the ids of friends which user A receives notifications about.

MySQL --> users (table) --> trackers (field) --> 2,3,4 (value).

The MySQL server must seperate the value by the comma in just one query. I think it will be friendlier to the server if the server only execute a single query instead of one query per value with a PHP foreach.

I need a query like: SELECT * FROM users WHERE in (SELECT trackers FROM users WHERE id = $me SEPERATED BY ,)

Comment: Not to nitpick too much, but this is a classic example of why one shouldn't use "csv fields" and use a separate table instead...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My feeling on this is that the table design is not correct for what you wish to achieve. My personal approach would have been to seperate the trackers into a table of its own. Since a user is basically tracking another user, the table will link up twice with the user table.

See my suggested table design below.

[image: Suggested Table Design]

This design will thus allow you to select all the user a user is tracking via a query such as the one below:

```
SELECT users.* 
FROM trackers
INNER JOIN users ON id = tracker
WHERE user.id = {your user id}
```

Comment: +1 `user` **has_many** `user` **through** `trackers`. It's basically just a follower/friend table.

Answer (score 0):

I've always found that for queries like yours doing 2 queries is usually the best solution.

The first:

```
SELECT trackers FROM users WHERE `user_id` = $me
```

then the 2nd, implode the results of the first into:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE `id` IN (".implode(',',$results).")
```

Not sure if that is the *best* solution, but in my experience it's made a huge difference to page load times on some sites I work on.